# Why does combination of packages cause capital T and F to be smaller than rest of alphabet?

Tags: capitalization

Today I came across a phaenomen I still don't understand, even after multiple hours of investigation.

A certain combination of packages and settings causes the **capital T and F to be smaller** then the rest of the alphabet and I'd like to understand why and how to avoid this.

[image]

The issue appears with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
12pt,
parskip=true,
listof=totoc,
footlines=2,
headsepline,
footsepline,
DIV=calc]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[colorlinks,
    pdfpagelabels,
    pdfstartview = FitH,
    bookmarksopen = true,
    bookmarksnumbered = true,
    linkcolor = black,
    urlcolor = black,
    plainpages = false,
    hypertexnames = false,
    citecolor = black] {hyperref}


\begin{document}
    
\section{Nominal TEU}

I do not like that the T in TEU is smaller than the E and U. Also the T in TPC appears to be smaller than the P and C. Why is the T in TEU and the T in TPC smaller than the other capital letters? Also, F in FEU appears to be smaller.

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

\end{document}
```

I already found out that either of the following will "solve" the issue:

1. Removing the options for documentclass and only stating `\documentclass{scrartcl}`
2. Loading package `fontenc` without options as `\usepackage{fontenc}`
3. Loading package `hyperref` without option `pdfstartview = FitH`

Does anyone know why this happens and what might be the rootcause?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, but removing the hyperref option only changes the zoom in your PDF viewer, so probably you are seeing a visual artifact.

Comment: This is interesting - I just experimented with the zoom and the difference in size appears at different zoom levels depending on the loaded packages. If no workaround is applied or with workaround 3 it shows up at 131 % using Adobe PDF Reader. With workaround 1 it shows up at 125 % or 150 % but only for T. With workaround 2 it does not appear at all. 

Is there a way to avoid this at all?

Btw. using VS Code and extension LaTeX Workshop to compile with `latexmk` on Win10.

Comment: if you remove the 12pt you get a different fontsize, and removing fontenc changes the font too, so yes that can have an effect. Check the settings in the reader, there are a few options regarding the resolution and how to handle text.

Comment: what tex system are you using, and do you have cm-super installed (epsecially if you use miktex)

Comment: check your log ends `)</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx1728.pfb>
Output written on ....`  specifically that it's using pfb fonts not pk

Comment: Seems to be the same ending as your `<c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx1728.pfb>` So it's probably texlive and cm-super is installed.

Comment: then you are using type1 fonts and the output you show is rather weird and unexpected